# How the Hadoop History Server is working?

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

There are 2 properties within configuration files I am confused with:

1. The property `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` in `yarn-site.xml`:

   a.) This property controls, where the logs of map/reduce tasks will be logged?

   b.) This is the responsibility of Node Manager (NM)?
2. The property `mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir` from `mapred-site.xml`:

   a.) Job related files like configurations etc. are stored in this location?

   b.) This is the responsibility of Application Master (AM)?
3. Does the History Server (HS) **combines** both of these information and shows a **consolidated** information in UI?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enabled log-aggregation,

- **1.a.** This is the log-aggregation dir, usually HDFS where NMs aggregate container-logs to.
- **1.b.** Yes.
- **2.a.** Yes.
- **2.b.** No. MR JobHistory Server will do that, by deleting JobSummary file and mv other files to ${mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir} from ${mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir}.
- **3.** Yes. MR JobHistory Server Web, includes job info(from ${mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir}) and container logs(from ${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}).